# Are there any other frameworks (besides Cappucino) for building a desktop-like app in browser?

Tags: web-applications, cappuccino, objective-j

I would like to build an app which would be very similar to http://gomockingbird.com (will draw the mockups). Are there any other frameworks, besides Cappucino, for that? I dislike Objective-J syntax and built-in Cappucino pseudo-mac interfaces. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/) and [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com).

Comment: I've just had a brief look at them and it seems to me that both are more about interface elements, when I will need some drawing stuff (like Rectangles and Lines, for example).

Comment: They are much more complicated than rectangles and lines. They are full UI frameworks complete with desktop-style widgets and their own event-handling styles that work in the same way as most desktop UI frameworks. I would suggest you look deeper into how they work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for drawing frameworks, it will be worth checking out [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/), which you could use in conjunction with the UI widgets provided by the frameworks Marc mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Are you aware that http://gomockingbird.com/  is actually built with Cappucino & Objective-J?